# Reading X axis from i2c library with a HMC5883L

Tags: python, i2c

I using a HMC5883L with the i2c library. I am using this code to get the direction it is facing

```
from i2clibraries import i2c_hmc5883l

hmc5883l = i2c_hmc5883l.i2c_hmc5883l(1)
hmc5883l.setContinuousMode()
hmc5883l.setDeclination(0,6)
print(hmc5883l)
```

But this prints all of the axises and I just want the x-axis but I do not know how just get the x-axis alone so I can compare x values. If anyone knows how to do this your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from i2clibraries import i2c_hmc5883l

mag_sensor = i2c_hmc5883l.i2c_hmc5883l(1)

mag_sensor.setContinuousMode()
mag_sensor.setDeclination(0,6)

var = str( mag_sensor)
var = var.partition("\n")[0]
print(var)
```